# Why initializer list do not move elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have been surprised to find that this simple exemple does not compile:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using vt = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>;
using at = std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>,1>;
int main(){
    auto a = at{std::make_unique<int>(10)}; //compile fine
    auto v = vt{std::make_unique<int>(10)}; //error
}
```

Why is there no vector constructor taking as argument type `initializer_list<T>&&` ?

Comment: Having such a constructor won't do you any good either way. Once you have an initializer list, copying the list doesn't copy the elements. The compiler is complaining because it can't populate the list to begin with.

Comment: `std::vector` elements must be "CopyAssignable", but `unique_ptr` isn't.

Comment: @alain - That is incorrect. The restrictions on the type held in the vector depend on how the vector is used (since C++11). You can have a vector of `unique_ptr`s just fine.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right @StoryTeller, thanks.